# Asterisk (VOIP) port forwarding on TP-LINK

Tags: router, port-forwarding, asterisk, ubuntu-16.04, voip

I have local asterisk server on UBUNTU 16.04. It's address 192.168.0.101:5060 and I would like to be allowed to talk with other users when I am outside local network. I tried [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e51ty.jpg) but it doesn't work. I am not good at network engineering. IS there any way to do this well?

Answer (score 1):

You need an internal service port as well.  I would caution you though about opening up an Asterisk server to the world.  They are rich targets to folks who want to make phone calls without paying for them.

Comment: what should port number be in internal port? it's default same as service port (5060)

Comment: The external port number is arbitrary, the internal port is the port the internal server is listening on.  So in your case it should be 5060.

Comment: I had set 5060, are there more requirements to make this works? My iptables is off, but client can't connect to server. In local area it works fine.

Comment: or maybe is there any safer way to make it works?

Comment: If you're trying to do SIP, which it appears you are, you also need 10000 through 20000 forwarded. Your router probably allows a range to be forwarded.  https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/port+forwarding

The article is showing how to do it with iptables, but the ports are the same no matter what you're using to forward.

Comment: Securing an Asterisk deployment is a broad topic unfit for discussion here.  To get started with understanding it, you could read https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+security  Lots of good links at the end as well.